# Checking quasicoherence on a qcqs scheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ be a scheme and $\mathscr{F}$ be an $\mathscr{O}_X$-module. It can be shown that $\mathscr{F}$ is quasicoherent iff for every *affine* open $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $s\in A$, the canonical morphism
$$
\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})_s\to \Gamma(D(s),\mathscr{F})
$$
is an isomorphism. In particular, when $X$ is qcqs, by the equalizing sequence of sheaves and five lemma, the above statement holds for global sections when $\mathscr{F}$ is quasicoherent. More precisely, when $\mathscr{F}$ is quasicoherent, for any $s\in \Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ the canonical morphism 
$$
\Gamma(X,\mathscr{F})_s\to \Gamma(X_s,\mathscr{F})
$$
is an isomorphism.

I am interested in in the converse. I believe it is not true in general, so I am seeking a counter-example:

> Give a qcqs scheme $X$ and an $\mathscr{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{F}$ such that for any $s\in \Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ the canonical morphism 
>   $$
> \Gamma(X,\mathscr{F})_s\to \Gamma(X_s,\mathscr{F})
> $$ 
>   is an isomorphism but $\mathscr{F}$ is not quasicoherent. Further, can we find an example where $X$ is affine, or is the statement true for affine $X$?

Comment: I think the statement should be true for affine $X$, because the distinguished open subsets form a basis.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm sorry, when $X$ is affine, I don't see how $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{F})_s\cong \Gamma(D(s),\mathscr{F})$ implies on distinguished open $\Gamma(D(f),\mathscr{F})_s\to \Gamma(D(fs),\mathscr{F})$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Both sides become $\Gamma(X,\mathscr F)_{fs}$ (you need to check that some maps agree).

Comment: @Remy This is what we need to prove, that both sides are $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{F})_{fs}$. Why is that true? We don't have $\mathscr{F}$ quasicoherent.

Comment: But you do have your assumption on the whole space $X$; apply it to $fs$ and to $f$ (instead of $s$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a counterexample, consider $X = \mathbb P^1_k$, and let $\mathscr F$ be *any* sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules. Note that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X) = k$, and every nonzero element in $k$ is already invertible on all of $X$. Thus, $X_s = X$ for all $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal O_X)\setminus\{0\}$, so the condition on $\mathscr F$ is vacuous.

(To find a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules which is not quasi-coherent, take for example $j_! \mathcal O_U$, where $U = D(x_0) \cong \mathbb A^1_k$ is a standard open, and $j \colon U \to X$ the inclusion.)